# Copying Content From Multiple TextBoxes to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

I'm looking to copy content from multiple textboxes to one textarea or straight to the clipboard using HTML/JS.

E.g Text1 = 123 Text2 = 456 Text3 = 789
I need to output it as

123

456

789

Without the spaces - So Far I have

```
 function Copy1() {
 if(window.clipboardData) {
 window.clipboardData.clearData();
 window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById('Text3').value);
```

This is okay for copying 1 textbox but I need to copy multiple textboxes and line break the content is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying

```
function Copy1() {
     if(window.clipboardData) {
         window.clipboardData.clearData();
         window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById('Text1').value+'\n'+
                                              document.getElementById('Text2').value+'\n'+
                                              document.getElementById('Text3').value);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function kopyala() {
        //Ekrandaki text vb. alanların tümü uygun formatta kopyala değişkenine atılır.
        var kopyala = "";
        kopyala = document.getElementById('metin-alani').value + '\n' +
            document.getElementById('text-alani').value + '\n' +
            document.getElementById('text2-alani').value;

        //Clipboard için kopyala değişkenindeki veriler gizli-alana atılıyor.
        document.getElementById('gizli-alan').value = "";
        document.getElementById('gizli-alan').value = kopyala;                    

        console.log(kopyala ? 'Panoya Atıldı' : 'Panoya Atılamadı');
        console.log(kopyala);

        try {
            //Gizli alandaki veriler clipboarda atılıyor.
            //document.getElementById('gizli-alan').select();
            document.getElementById('gizli-alan').select();
            document.execCommand('copy');       

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);

        }

    }


</script>
```

```
<textarea id="metin-alani" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="text" id="text-alani" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="text2-alani" />
<br />
<button onclick="kopyala()">Panoya Kopyala</button>


<textarea id="gizli-alan" style="width:1px;height:1px" />
```